# Android Watch: 'cannot resolve symbol' error on GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watchface

I'm trying to set up a watch using the calendar class. 
The line:

```
Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault())
```

gives me an error:

> cannot resolve symbol GregorianCalendar error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_Julian_and_Gregorian_calendars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to add

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
```

to the Java class in question?

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to import android.util.GregorianCalendar. Your suggestion, java.util.GregorianCalendar, fixed the trouble. Thank you!

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, you might try changing Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import. Also, ctrl-alt-O will optimize your imports for you.

Comment: Thank you again. Auto import will help a great deal. As will the auto optimize.